# Favorite - unfavorite buttons and animations

Tags: buttons, animation

I'm designing a web app that allows registered users to favorite / unfavorite quotes. I'm not sure if I have a comprehensive approach for a user.

You can view or download a short [movie clip that shows how the UI reacts](http://antoine-augusti.fr/fav-unfav.mov) when favoriting and suppressing a quote from favorites.

For your information, I'm removing a quote from my favorites first and then I add a quote to my favorites.

I want to have your thoughts on my approach and how I can improve the user experience.

Comment: Hi Antoine, this question is primarily opinion based an d doesn't have a clear and definite answer, consider narrowing it down to one or two specific concerns you have or improvements you'd like to make. General "Can I  have feedback on X" questions usually get put on hold by moderators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation is weird. I think it will confuse the user.

The classic star/heart filled when you favorite the associated quote is the best way.
For instance, if you see this icon: "♡", and then this icon "❤", you will understand that the second is favorites.

The best way is always the most understandable way. If you want to add an animation, you can change the border on mouseover, and fill the heart/star on the click.